# CSS not working in chrome but does work in firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have created a class called "titles" and for some reason it does not want to work in chrome.  I looked at the page in Firefox and it was fine.  Below is the code:

```css
.titles {
            font-size: 4.5em;
            color: #154;
            text-shadow: 1px 2px #000;
            }
```

```html
<h1 class="titles"><b>DREWSPLAINING</b></h1>
```

the change I made was adding the text-shadow.  Prior to that, the CSS was fine.  Now, even when I remove the test shadow portion it doesn't work properly.

Comment: It works fine in both. Maybe you need to clear your cache in chrome, use Ctrl + F5.

Comment: Press `Ctr + Shift + R` in chrome.

Comment: UPDATE:  I checked the site on MS Edge and Chrome on my wife's computer and the CSS works - yet on my laptop (where I write the code) and on my phone, the CSS is not showing...

Comment: The Ctrl F5 worked - I had just been hitting F5 alone.  Thanks!

Comment: @Drew You better delete this question as this is of no use to other visitors.

Comment: @Drew No problem

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. May be you should clear you cache.

Comment: It should be a comment, not a solution post.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the demo, it works in all the browser. Might be you have added some css to the .title class on the other place.

Also you can try to clear cache.

```css
.titles {
        font-size: 4.5em;
        color: #154;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px #000;
        }
```

```html
<div class="titles">
Stack overflow
<div>
```

Comment: What's the significance of pasting the same codes of the question into the answer?

Comment: I'm on app and some times the code directly pasted in the answer.